# Using aes_decrypt and fetch_assoc

Tags: php, mysql, encryption, mysqli

My code was working great. But then I decided I would encrypt values before I store them in the database. I am using aes_encrypt to encrypt values when storing them in the database. I am using aes_decrypt to decrypt the values when retrieved/selected from the database. This allowed me to use the column name as the element of the associative array, but now the element name is all messed up. Here is my code:

```
$databaseObject = connectToDB();
$result = $databaseObject->query("SELECT AES_DECRYPT(column_name, '".ENCRYPT_KEY."') FROM tempTable WHERE `id` = 3");
$assoc_array = $result->fetch_assoc();
var_dump($assoc_array);
echo $assoc_array['column_name'];
```

This code outputs the following:

```
array(1) { ["AES_DECRYPT(column_name, '6da6365bd886f275731d4662c0c29992fdd59a5d')"]=> string(7) "siracha" } siracha
```

The value in the column is `siracha` and the column name is `column_name`.

I want to continue using an associative array, but I don't want to use `$assoc_array["AES_DECRYPT(column_name, '6da6365bd886f275731d4662c0c29992fdd59a5d')"]` to get the values. The `6da6365bd886f275731d4662c0c29992fdd59a5d` part is the key I used to encrypt the data before storing the value in the database.

Many thanks to your always helpful suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First: **Do not do encryption in MySQL.** Passing encryption keys to the database engine is unsafe, as it can easily lead to your encryption keys being present in an output web page (e.g, if your PHP application displays the contents of a query), in web server logs (particularly `error_log`), or in MySQL statement or binary logs. It will also transmit your encryption key over the network, *unencrypted*, if your MySQL server is not on the local machine, and will expose it on the MySQL server in `SHOW PROCESSLIST` while such a query is running. Using it with a fixed key also makes it next to impossible to change the encryption key if it is compromised. In short, it's an incredibly bad security practice. Do encryption in your application, not the database!

---

Now that I've got that out of the way, what you want is the `AS` column modifier:

```
SELECT AES_DECRYPT(...) AS decrypted_data FROM ...
```

This will rename the column to `decrypted_data`. (Or whatever you like.)